# How do I format a spring-data-jpa native query for postgres

Tags: spring-data-jpa, nativequery

I'm trying to query a postgres database from a jpa repository with this:

```
@Query(value =
    "SELECT " +
        "string_agg(distinct customer_po, ', ') as customer_po, " +
        "customer_part, " +
        "description, " +
        "bunzl_loc, " +
        "sum(dayspastexpected) as longestGrouping, " +
        "string_agg(distinct priority, ', '), " +
        "sum(open_qty) as totalBoQty, " +
        "sum(current_oh) as sunAvail, " +
        "next_receipt " +
    "FROM " +
        "sap_data.openorders_report " +
    "WHERE " +
        "run_date between :from and :to " +
    "AND " +
        "backorderorfuture = 'Future' " +
    "GROUP BY " +
        "customer_part, " +
        "bunzl_loc, " +
        "description, " +
        "next_receipt " +
    "ORDER BY " +
        "customer_part desc, " +
        "bunzl_loc desc /*#pageable*/",
    nativeQuery = true)
Page<SapOpenOrder> getBackOrderReport(@Param("from") Date from, @Param("to") Date to, Pageable pageable);
```

but I'm getting this error:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "WHERE"
```

I can run this query in dbeaver and get the correct results. How can I run this query with spring jpa?

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't yet, update to a recent version of Spring Data JPA. 
Then remove the `/*#pageable*/`. 
That was a hack to work around a bug in Spring Data JPA, which is now fixed.
See https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJPA-928 for details.

If that doesn't solve the issue, update your question with SQL statement that actually gets executed. 
You can obtain that statement from the logs after configuring logging for your JPA implementation.